# Google URL Shortener API -

Tags: curl, google-api, short-url

New to APIs... I was looking to the documentation here (https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) and couldn't get the following command to work:

```
  curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=<MYAPIKEY> \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

Received this error message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: shortUrl",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "shortUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: shortUrl"
 }
}
```

Not sure why they're asking for a shortUrl parameter, isn't what I'm looking for them to return to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct example and you probably did something else wrong. The API is working correctly and shortening the URL with your provided example.

Are you sure that you did not finish executing the command at the first backslash (`\`), because if you do that it would return with the error what you experiencing. Make sure you run the whole command at once. You can also join the multiple lines into one and remove the backslashes.

So running this command (without providing the content and the HTTP headers):

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=<MYAPIKEY>
```

Would return the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: shortUrl",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "shortUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: shortUrl"
 }
}
```

Comment: Swear I tried that before but this time it worked - thank you! :)